# My program for checking the contents and length of the string is having some issues

Tags: c, c-strings, strcmp, strlen

I am not able to type the second input in the command prompt, it says my program has stopped. I am just trying my own code.
I have added two functions to check for the length and contents of the string.
And i can simply use strcmp(), but i am avoiding to use that for practice.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int lencompare(char *str1, char *str2){
    int len1, len2;
    len1 = strlen(str1);
    len2 = strlen(str2);
    return (len1==len2) ? 1 : 0;
}
int compare(char *str1, char *str2){
    int i =0, flag=0;
    if(lencompare(str1, str2)==1){
        while(*(str1+i) != '\0');
        {
            if(*(str1+i) == *(str2+i))
             flag = 1;
            else
             flag = 0;
            i++;
        }
        return flag;
    }
    if(lencompare(str1, str2) == 0){
        printf("Length is Different");
    }
}
int main(){
    char *str1 , *str2 ;
    fgets(str1, 20, stdin);
    fgets(str2, 20, stdin);
    if(compare(str1, str2) == 1){
        printf("both length and content are same");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what output does your program show you? A Screenshot would be lovely.

Comment: str1 and str2 need to be buffers, up to 20 chars - you haven't allocated the memory for them. try char str1[ 21 ], str2[ 21 ];

Comment: You should revise your use of `flag`. You keep setting and clearing it. Initialise it to `1` and set it to `0` if any characters are different. If they are the same, don't touch it. Also in `int compare()` not all control paths return a value (see compiler warnings).

Comment: [How do strings and char arrays work in C?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12718929)

Comment: `str1[i]` is the same thing and a lot easier to understand than `*(str1+i)`.

Answer (score 6):

For starters these variables

```
char *str1 , *str2 ;
```

are not initialized. So the program already has undefined behavior. You need to declare character arrays like for example

```
enum { N = 20 };
char str1[N], str2[N];
```

The standard function `fgets` can append the new line character `'\n'` to the entered string provided that there is enough space in the character array.

You should remove this character. For example

```
fgets(str1, 20, stdin);
fgets(str2, 20, stdin);

str1[ strcspn( str1, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
str2[ strcspn( str2, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

The function `lencompare` should be declared and defined like

```
int lencompare( const char *str1, const char *str2 )
{
    return strlen( str1 ) == strlen( str2 );
}
```

The function `compare` has undefined behavior because in some paths of execution it returns nothing.

Also it should be declared like

```
int compare( const char *str1, const char *str2 );
```

Within the function you two times call the function `lencompare`:

```
if(lencompare(str1, str2)==1){
```

and

```
if(lencompare(str1, str2) == 0){
```

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int lencompare( const char *str1, const char *str2 )
{
    return strlen( str1 ) == strlen( str2 );
}

int compare( const char *str1, const char *str2 )
{
    int equal = lencompare( str1, str2 );

    if ( equal )
    {
        while ( *str1 == *str2 && *str1 ) 
        {
            ++str1;
            ++str2;
        }           

        equal = *str1 == *str2;
    }

    return equal;
}   

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 20 };
    char str1[N], str2[N];

    fgets( str1, sizeof( str1 ), stdin );
    fgets( str2, sizeof( str2 ), stdin );

    str1[ strcspn( str1, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
    str2[ strcspn( str2, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

    if ( compare( str1, str2 ) )
    {
        puts( "both length and content are same" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Sridhar
Sridhar
both length and content are same
```

Pay attention to that instead of the while loop in the function `compare` you could use the standard C function `strcmp`. In this case the function compare will be very simple

```
int compare( const char *str1, const char *str2 )
{
    return strcmp( str1, str2 ) == 0;
}
```

In fact there is no need to compare preliminary the lengths of the strings.